# Is this quadrilateral tangential?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, geometry

Related: [Is this quadrilateral cyclic?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/176162/78410)

### Background

A [tangential quadrilateral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentialQuadrilateral.html) is a quadrilateral which has an incircle:

[image]

Examples include any square, rhombus, or a kite-like shape. Rectangles or parallelograms in general are not tangential.

### Task

Given the four vertices of a quadrilateral (as Cartesian coordinates), determine if it is tangential.

### Input & output

For input, it is allowed to use any format that unambiguously specifies the four vertices' coordinates (eight real or floating-point numbers). You can assume the following on the input:

- The points specify a simple convex quadrilateral, i.e. all internal angles are strictly less than 180 degrees, and the edges meet only at the vertices.
- The points are specified in counter-clockwise order (or the other way around if you want).

For output, you can use one of the following:

- Truthy/falsy values as defined by your language of choice (swapping the two is allowed), or
- Two consistent values for true/false respectively.

It is acceptable if your code produces wrong output due to floating-point inaccuracies.

### Test cases

#### Tangential

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)  # unit square
(-2, 0), (0, 1), (2, 0), (0, -1)  # rhombus
(1, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, 2), (4, 2)  # kite
(0, 0), (50, 120), (50, 0), (32, -24)  # all four sides different
```

#### Not tangential

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)  # rectangle
(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 0)  # parallelogram
```

### Scoring & winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is complex number input allowed?

Comment: @xnor Yes, it's allowed.

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
5:)d|2e!sd
```

Input is a vector of four complex numbers. Output is `0` (which is falsy) if tangential, or nonzero (which is truthy) if not tangential.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39RKM6XGKFWxOOX//2hDXaMsHQVdI13DLAVdQ20QxwRIxgIA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/USjOlxihVsTjlv0vI/2gDbYMsHQUDbcMsBUMgoQMkDbJiuaJ1jeASOgpQtq4hSMZQ1wjI0TUC8hR0DbVBHBMgCZSBmGUK1GMEZYAoYyNdIxOENMxEmLlwCYj1xggJBQA).

#### Explanation

The code computes the difference between sums of lengths of opposite sides. This difference is zero [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral#Characterizations) the quatrilateral is tangential.

```
5:   % Range [1 2 3 4 5]
)    % Implicit input: complex vector of length 4. Index into it modularly.
     % This repeats the first vertex after the last
d    % Consecutive differences
|    % Absolute value, element-wise
2e   % Reshape as a 2-column matrix, in column-major order
!    % Transpose
s    % Sum of each column. Gives a vector of length 2
d    % Consecutive difference
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>89</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>59</s></sup> 55 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum((-1)**i*abs(l[i-1]-l[i])for i in range(4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNboMwEIX3nGLEpjbCFSRZRWLbS6QshtQQq/6htpHaVDk79YCUIjXd2E/P88143vgVL87u5755nTWa7g1BH8NkGBM1LwpVYBeYPilRtyJdLe@dBwXKgkc7SHbgfL42Z2dGLT@zKEMM0MApA8aurCqh4iUsol5EvREVTyqfrIoQPib0MuflyondH3DrpJ8R6S/OdFO4U6ml2C01xIuVE8ldzQMJ4t5V/B1VPZq0GUnAIK30qMHLc0xL6wf0fa/9v/SI6dRSu8GjoQ5tRllSZCVYNJJCXQI8ZjB6ZSPr85dUgfBNzzdQ8Skk7SL0jAr57Tnn2fwD)

A list of vertices as complex numbers is passed in. The lengths of the sides \$(a, b, c, d)\$ are calculated and uses \$a+c=b+d\$ for a tangential quadrilateral. Returns's a falsy value (0) for a tangential or a truthy value (nonzero) otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,i=3:i+1and abs(l[i]-l[i-1])-f(l,i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNasMwEIX3OsXgTSVqBSvuKuBtLxG8GCeyI6ofV5KhScnZXcmG1NB0Mzy9mW8eo/EaL87W89w3Gk13RtClauqDehVoz4BdoPqoWp4KFy3jPU19Lth8a07OjFp@kShDDNDAkQClN1qVULESFiEWITaiYkkVk1URwueEXhasXDm@/wNunZSZSX9xppvCg0or@X6ZyTxfOZ7c1XzLInMfKv5GVc@SNpEZGKSVHjV4eYpoB/2EftxV/0uPmKqW2g0eTd7Qkt55yF9WgkUjQdnlFQ4ERq9spH3xniYQvnP7Diq@hKRdhJ7mQXbfFYzMPw)

Take complex number input. Outputs as Truthy/Falsey swapped. Test cases [from Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197715/20260).

---

**48 bytes**

```python
lambda a,b,c,d:A(a-b)+A(c-d)-A(b-c)-A(d-a)
A=abs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBbsMgEETvfMXKl0ALlZ30FMkHX/ITbQ@LjR2rGFzAUpsq3@6CLaWWml5gGObtCMavcLbmMLfl66xxkA0Ccslr3hwrikKyx4rWomGiolLUaWsEMlKVKP18KWs7jFp9kqB88FDCCwFKLzTnkDMOiygWUWxEzqLKJtMH8B8TOpUxvnJi/wfcOqJYSHe2g5z8jYojxX7JJF6snIjuaj4nkbj3PvxW5feaNpUJ6JRRDjU4VQc0nb5D3951@JceMa5aads5HNKEN9JaB@nLOBgcFPRmOfkjgdH1JtA2O8UEwne6vkIfdj5qG6ClDynJrk8ZI/MP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ṁ5ạƝŒœ§E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkbTh7sWHpt7dNLRyYeWu/4/OunhzhnWjxrmKOjaKTxqmGt9uJ3rcNvD3d2H2x81rYn8/z@aK1rDQEfBQFNHAUQbgmgjBG2gGaujoKCsUJSaXJKYl56TiqTcEKrMGFN5QWJRYk5Oak5@elFiLhYbDBE0TEtpXmaJQnFhaWIRyA5dI0w3wfi6hjBHZeTnJpUWA5UDzdE1AkmD9OmCNegCxcBCJiA6FqQ@O7MklSsWAA)

### Explanation

```
5ị€       | Modular index 1,2,3,4,5 into list
   ạƝ     | Absolute difference of neighbouring pairs
     Œœ   | Split into odd and even indices
       §  | Sum of inner lists
        E | Equal
```

A monadic link taking a list of complex coordinates and returning 1 for tangential and 0 for not.

Based on [@LuisMendo’s MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197714/42248) so be sure to upvote that one!

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte!

Comment: `5ị€` can be `ṁ5`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

Takes input as a list of coordinate pairs. Returns \$0\$ (falsy) for tangential or a non-zero value (truthy) for non-tangential.

```javascript
a=>(g=_=>Math.hypot(([x,y]=a[i],[X,Y]=a[++i&3],x-X),y-Y))(i=0)-g()+g()-g()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDLbsMgEEX3@QpWNciQ@JEuyR@kqy4SuaiiLrFpCLgYV/HXu2CljdPIiyKhOwy6Zx4f/Iu3pZWNI9q8i@FAB043sKKvdLPlrl7WfWMchMUZ94zyQjJc7PA@hHEsH3KGz2SHcE/2CEFJE0QqiGJ/gw6l0a1RYqlMBaNnriuhneQqQovpzwEWRYJBwjAImgZNr5owhhC4nNUKdFo60H523Io7DMn@cCZvkl5BHmNrc3rr2juEr0iyYAksMkKIz42pddALxCOO0onZSR5DC9lvOAZ5QGbrgFjcGKMX/WQccP9ZUTYd8XZFVpQBpea7@9lvPg9puOVKCe@0/DR8Aw)

Comment: I added a test case where all four sides have different lengths, and your code seems to fail on it.

Comment: @Bubbler Now fixed. My optimization was silly.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>17</s> 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-6 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)

outputs 1 if tangential, 0 if not

```apl
0=-/|2-/5⍴⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@ufo2Rrr7po94tj/qmgoT@P@qdqxCSmJeemleSmZijkJxYnFrMpQAGBVwGWQYKBlmGCoZgbAAXP7TeCCoDoQ@tN4TLGQJ5RgogFUBRIG2YZaRgkmWEYqYpUKsRmDJQMAYpNDLh4gK5xC8/T6GEkGuMIPaiiINcaAwRBwA)

Explanation:

```apl
0=-/|2-/5⍴⎕

          ⎕ take 4 complex numbers as evaluated input
        5⍴   reshape to 5
     2-/     difference between each pair of numbers
    |        absolute value
  -/         alternating sum
0=           the quadrilateral is tangential if the final result is 0
```

### Previous answer

```apl
=/+/⍉2 2⍴|2-/5⍴⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@tvrb@o95OIwWjR71baox09U2B9KO@qSDZ/4965yqEJOalp@aVZCbmKCQnFqcWcymAQQGXQZaBgkGWoYIhGBvAxQ@tN4LKQOhD6w3hcoZAnpECSAVQFEgbZhkpmGQZoZhpCtRqBKYMFIxBCo1MuLhALvHLz1MoIeQaI4i9KOIgFxpDxAE)

Explanation:

```apl
=/+/⍉2 2⍴|2-/5⍴⎕

                ⎕  take 4 complex numbers as evaluated input
              5⍴    reshape to 5
           2-/      find the difference between each pair of numbers
          |         absolute value
      2 2⍴          reshape to 2x2 matrix
    ⍉              transpose
  +/                sum the rows
=/                  are they both equal?
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@Bra5@jZGuvumj3i2P@qaCBP8/6p2rEJKYl56aV5KZmKOQnFicWsylAAYFXAZZBgoGWYYKhmBsABc/tN4IKgOhD603hMsZAnlGCiAVQFEgbZhlpGCSZYRipilQqxGYMlAwBik0MuHiArnELz9PoYSQa4wg9qKIg1xoDBEHAA) using alternating sum `-/`.

Comment: Thanks, @Bubbler I didn't knkow about that

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

Returns `Sphere` if the quadrilateral is tangential, `Insphere` if it is not.

```
Head@Insphere@Polygon@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xD4IwEIX/yiUkTFwsBUdNR9xwJgyNFiGRYrAOpulvr1wNAk7v3ct3966XplW9NN1F@gYOvlDyKk76@WjVqEQ53N@3QYso9uXYaVNFgEc4vzplRFNFdQ0x7ARYa1kCzCVAmpKmizJHxiL/Q1Yzpl9mopGTIxgDhVMWopw0UHPXni7xnw0mo0Web8FV49K8IeZ3sw3hvP8A)

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 38 bytes

Returns `True` if the quadrilateral is tangential, `False` if it is not.

```
0=={1,-1,1,-1}.Norm/@(#-RotateLeft@#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoMwDIZfJVCQDdrZVnd09AHG2HYVD2VU5kEFyU6lz96ZglN3yf8nfMmf3uLb9Ra7l40tVFFWlVdcKE4lnG7j1OfmwMRzRIvu6lo07JjF@9QNWDMQF3h8OoemrVnTQAa5Ae@95CADB1JFqlaVgYwX@g/Z9HNwYmZaaHIEi0TNj0EalaSJWrLOdEn/bDIFLepyD24S1@Qdsbxb7IgQ4xc)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
ĆüαnOtιOË
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m5mKvpGBrp6Bk//9I2@E95zbm@Zec2@l/uPu/zv/oaAMdBYNYHQUQbQiiDRG0QWwsV3S0rhGaCiS@riFYCVCtrhFICKRWF6xIFygGFjIB0SBFMItMQeYYwZlghjFIn5EJijok6xDWIiuAudQYRQEA)

Port of [Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197718/6484). It turned out pretty short, despite 05AB1E's lack of complex numbers.